# I cannot find the general formula for least perimeter when a specific number of squares are given

Tags: optimization, generating-functions

A figure is formed by placing $N$ unit squares squares on the plane.  Squares may share a common edge, but they may not otherwise overlap.  What is the minimum perimeter of the figure?

Through drawing all the possible cases, I got that

a. For a square number $N^2$, the least perimeter is $4\cdot N$.

b. For $N^2-1$, the least perimeter isn't greater than $4\cdot N$.

But this does not satisfy for example $8$ number of tiles. So it seems to work as long as we keep the shape convex.

At last I can only say that for $K$ tiles, where $K$ is less than or equal to $N^2$, the least perimeter isn't greater than $4\cdot N$.

It can be of any shape, all matters is that the perimeter should be minimum. The individual pieces are squares

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's not clear what figure you are trying to draw with what pieces.

Comment: It can be of any shape, all matters is that the perimeter should be minimum. The individual pieces are squares.

Comment: Put the explanation in the body of the question, not the comments, please.

Comment: How did you prove the result when $N$ is a square?

Comment: 1 tile      p = 4 * sqrt(1) = 4 * 1 =  4

  4 tiles     p = 4 * sqrt(4) = 4 * 2 =  8

  9 tiles     p = 4 * sqrt(9) = 4 * 3 = 12

Comment: So you just made some examples?

Comment: @saulspatz can you please edit the question, to make the statement more clear? I can't understand the problem

Comment: @saulspatz it's a pattern being followed

Comment: @AdityaDeSaha How's that?

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, makes sense.

Comment: I am not able to guess that pattern sir. I made a list till 30 squares but can't guess the pattern. @saulspatz

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to solve a simpler problem " Given a perimeter value $p$, how large a shape can you make with perimeter $p$?" Using the solution to that problem, try to estimate $P_N$.

The answer is $$P_N = 2\lceil2\sqrt{N}\rceil $$
The problem is the content of  a paper :

F. Harary and H. Harborth. Extremal animals. J. Combin. Inform. System Sci., 1:1–8, 1976. ( unfortunately I can't seem to find a soft copy of the same )

You can read the solution of a related problem [in this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f15c/db94769b434826bc8353096b9c2960d201f8.pdf)

I'm giving a **brief** outline of the proof:

Denote the area and perimeter of a polymino $P$ by $Ar(P)$ and $Pr(P)$ respectively. Define $\sigma(p) = \max\{ Ar(A): Pr(A) = p\}$ to be the maximum area obtainable by a polymino of perimeter $p$. We want to find $\pi(n) = \min\{Pr(A): Ar(A) = n\}$, the minimum perimeter of a $n$-polymino. We can compute $\sigma(p)$ to be 
    $$ \sigma(4k) = 4k^2, $$
    $$ \sigma(4k+2) = 4k^2 - 4k $$
    Now, we can show that:
    $$ \pi(n) = \min \{ p : \sigma(p) \ge n\} $$
    Considering two mutually disjoint cases $p = 4k$ and $p = 4k+2$, Its straightforward to get $\pi(k) = 2\lceil2\sqrt{k}\rceil$

Answer (score 0):

I have tried examples and derived at this function:

If k is a perfect square,

$ P_{k+1} = P_{k+2} = .... = P_{k+ \sqrt k} = P_k + 2$

$P_{k+ \sqrt k + 1} = P_k + 4$

For all other values of k, $ P_k = 4*\lceil {\sqrt k} \rceil$

Though i am not sure, but for small examples my formula seems to be correct.

Comment: I don't think you're saying what you mean to say.  When $k=4,$ we have $P_k=8,$ and your formulas give $P_5=10, P_6=12,$ but $P_6=10$

Comment: @saulspatz i did some mistake, thanks for pointing this out.  
Still this may be wrong.

Comment: I know, this is just a guess based on some examples.  So is my answer.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, anyway 
1->4,2->6,3->8,4->8,5->10,6->10,6->12,8->12,9->12,10->14,11->14,12->14,13->16,14->16,15->16 ... these are the values i got, if some differ from yours, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Examples lead me to believe that the answer is $$
P_k=
\begin{cases}
4n,&n(n-1)< k\le n^2,\\
4n+2,&n^2<k\le n(n+1)
\end{cases}
$$
but I have nothing like a proof.